# Only folders in the root of document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, document-library, folder

I want to create a document library where the users are only allowed to create/upload folders in the root of the library yet create/upload documents and other files types within the folders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement there is no direct solution there is a work around you can do, you need to create any document library name it as X and follow the steps below:

1. Enable content organizer feature on site.
2. That will create a Drop off library on site which will be used to route the documents to your specified folders.

For content organizer here is the [reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a)